# Shortcut for running vscode from anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

My current workflow for using vscode in anaconda is following:

- open vscode
- conda activate myenv
- navigate to my working directory
- code .

That opens vscode and python works as expected with all packages loaded in myenv.
Starting vscode with the windows start menu doesn't work, even though I tried a lot of things.
How can I make a shortcut for the above process, so that I don't have to do it every time I want to use vscode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use vscode to open your working directory as the workspace

   - Open the PowerShell or CMD in your working directory, type `code .`
   - Open VSCode and `File-->Open Folder...` to select your work folder

     [image]
2. Select the Conda environment interpreter

   [image]
3. `New Terminal` will automatically activate the environment (*Or run the script directly*)

   [image]

   [image]

In the case of not switching the workspace, the next time you open VSCODE, the next opening is still the current workspace.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer! This actually worked, although it seemed the most things were already set up as recommended. Not sure what did the trick in the end. On another note: how do I get that colorful command line?

Comment: I am glad that the answer is useful to you. You can try [Oh My Posh](https://ohmyposh.dev/). Have a nice day.